# Swift: private get and public set

Tags: swift

What I found until now is the scenario of a public get and private set like visible below.

```
private(set) var distanceTravelled: Double
```

I want it the other way around. Of course the following is not working.

```
private(get) public var distanceTravelled: Double
```

Comment: you want a public setter and a private getter for this variable?

Comment: I don't think you can. What's the use case for this?

Comment: The variable is just an example but what I want to do is fetching data from a web service, which is done in another class, and passing it to this variable. But no other class than the one holding the variable should access it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want a public setter but a private getter for this var you can declare it as private:

```
private var distanceTravelled: Double
```

and create a public method for setting this variable:

```
public func setDistanceTravelled(distanceTravelled: Double) {
    self.distanceTravelled = distanceTravelled
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is clear. But a hoped there could be a short form.

Comment: oh, so you were looking for shorthand declaration of this... well as mentioned by others I do not believe it is supported right from the box...

Comment: A shorthand would have allowed for other changes, such as appending and other mutating functions to have the same access declaration.

Answer (score 15):

I don't believe this is possible. To quote from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID17):

> You can give a setter a *lower* access level than its corresponding getter

That is, you can only alter the access in one direction, and that is to make the setter more restrictive than the getter.

Answer (score 13):

This ***is possible***, as of Xcode 10.2 / Swift 5.

You combine a computed property with an `@available` attribute, like this:

```
public var distanceTravelled: Double {
  @available(*, unavailable) 
  get { internalDistanceTravelled }

  set { internalDistanceTravelled = newValue }
}

private var internalDistanceTravelled: Double
```

Note that if you make `distanceTravelled` visible to Objective-C, the `unavailable` will not extend there.

Comment: Very smart. I'm assuming the `@available...` is so the getter won't cause problems if the variable is "gotten" outside the private scope, where it would be unavailable?

Comment: Thanks, but probably just trickstery ;). The `@available` generates the error when one tries to use the getter (and IIRC, removes the getter from autocomplete).

Comment: ahh interesting!

Answer (score 2):

```swift
// The setter is private to the scope. 
public private(set) var myVar

// The setter is private to the file, that's fairly niche
public fileprivate(set) var myVar 

// The setter is internal to your module, if you're doing a framework that's useful
public internal(set) var myVar
```

Comment: This misses (and inverts) the point of the question: public **set**, private **get**.

Answer (score -6):

You could do something like this:

```
private var _distanceTravelled: Double
var distanceTravelled: Double {
  get {
    fatalError("Access denied.")
  }
  set {
    _distanceTravelled = newValue
  }
}
```

Comment: So that if someone mistakenly calls its getter, the app will BOOM. I think this is not a solution.

Comment: @Andrew Eades the problem with your idea is that it makes your getter inaccessible even  inside the class, and at that point, you might as well just omit the getter.

Comment: @Franceso Replace the fatalError() with your own code. Throw an error if you wish or do nothing. The OP asked how to deny access to the get and this is an example. I modelled this on the behaviour you would get if accessing an array out of bounds so I think it is a perfectly good solution.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick you have access through `_distanceTravelled`.

Comment: This answer should not have been downvoted. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ It addresses the OP by showing how to have a public setter whilst making the getter inaccessible for a `var`. The better solution was unavailable at the time of posting but I think using the @available attribute as described by @Clay Bridges is better. Using a function to set a private variable is obvious and did not address the OP's question.

Comment: @AndrewEades Then why do you need a setter?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Because this question is about making a **setter** public whilst making the getter private in an analogous way to how you can make the setter private but leave the getter public as described in the OP.

Comment: But why then, do you need the "access denied"? if you're going to implement a doomed getter, you might as well try to make the error message look like the same error message when you try accessing a private value.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick There is no runtime error for accessing a private var; it is caught at compile time. The compiler allows an array out of bounds access to compile but crashes with an out of bounds error at runtime. I decided it was essentially the same issue - an attempt to access an out of bounds variable during run time. Therefore it was acceptable to error when an attempt to access this value is made at runtime in the same way

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick There is no runtime error for accessing a private var; it is caught at compile time. The compiler allows an array out of bounds access to compile but crashes with an out of bounds error at runtime. I decided it was essentially the same issue - an attempt to access an "out of bounds" variable during run time.
`let a = [0, 1, 2]; 
let b = a[3] // Fatal error: Index out of range`
This is why my solution causes a fatal error and why @Franceso comment that it is no solution is incorrect.  But I can see that I needed to explain this in my answer in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AndrewEades I still don't understand why you can't make the error message look like same error message when you try accessing a private value.

Comment: Spending a few minutes with a Swift Playground experimenting is a good way to get familiar with the concepts being discussed. Try putting a private var in a struct and accessing it from outside. That's a compile-time error. The fatal error above is a runtime error and any code that tries to access the "protected" var will compile without error so it needs a runtime error.